# PHPUnit on Laravel setUpBeforeClass can't find factory class

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am trying to run a unit test that enters data into a database before the test run. I have defined a setup method which runs for each test case which what I don't want. The setup method executes fine with no issue. What I want is to have the data entered into the db once and then used by all test cases. So I setup a static function setUpBeforeClass.

```
public static function setUpBeforeClass() : void {
    parent::setUpBeforeClass();
    static::$journalOption = new JournalOption;
    $this->user = factory(User::class)->create();


}
```

When the user factory class is called I get the following error:

InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\User]

The UserFactory.php file exists in database/factories/UserFactory.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;


$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

Comment: Do you have `use App\User;` in your test file above `public static function  setUpBeforeClass()`?

Comment: Yes I do have it specified above the class declaration Delena

Answer (score 9):

The `factory` function doesn't work properly in your `setUpBeforeClass` function, because the application isn't yet bootstrapped when that function is run. You could bootstrap the application and run the migrations in your `setUpBeforeClass` function, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Generally, you should create the data you need for each test separately in case another test modifies or deletes the data, or has other unexpected side effects. So it would be better if you keep the factory in your `setup()` function. You could use an in-memory SQLite database for your tests if you're worried about polluting your database.

Comment: Might go without saying, but I often forget to add `parent::setup()` if we override the `setup()` method.